# can I check a regular expression on one array element?

Tags: arrays, regex, nsregularexpression

I am trying to test if a specific element in an `array` is a range of characters, from a-z lowercase. what am I doing wrong? I am very new to coding (1 month in) and I am probably trying to do stuff thats too hard for me.

```
var array ["a","b","c"];
var myRegularExpression = /[a-z]/;
if (myRegularExpression.test(array[index]))  {      
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: **Many mistakes** **1.** Array Declaration: `var array = ["a","b","c"];` **2.** Regex should be `/^[a-z]+$/` **3.** To check if any of the element from array satisfies condition you need to **iterate over array**

Answer (score 1):

To give you a working example as @Tushar mentioned:

```js
var arr = ["a","b","c","123"];
var myRegularExpression = new RegExp("^[a-z]+$");
var matchCount = 0;
for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
  if (myRegularExpression.test(arr[index]))  {      
    //do stuff
    matchCount += 1;
  } 
}

document.getElementById("result").innerText = matchCount;
```

```html
Number of elements matching the regex "^[a-z]+$":
<div id="result"></div>
```